# Use Taylor series expansions to find three-point forward and backward expressions for $f'''(x)$?

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods, taylor-expansion

I'm not really sure how to begin this or what to do so any explanations or help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

Let's see how to derive the approximation for $f'(x)$ based on two points. Recall that
$$
f(x+h) = f(x) + hf'(x) + h^2f''(x)/2 + \ldots \\
f(x-h) = f(x) - hf'(x) + h^2f''(x)/2 \pm \ldots
$$

Note that if you ignore the 2nd order terms, you can solve for $f'(x)$ to get
$$
f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h},
$$
which involves 1 extra point $x+h$ besides the usual point of evaluation $x$.

Another approach would be to use $x$ and $x \pm h$. Add the two formulae above and ignore terms of 3rd order and higher:
$$
f(x+h) - f(x-h) = 2hf'(x)
$$
which yields a (more accurate) approximation
$$
f'(x) \approx \frac{f(x+h) - f(x-h)}{2h}
$$

Notice the first relationship uses $x$ and $x+h$, so it is *forward*, this second one is *central*, and *backward* would use $x$ and $x-h$.

Can you do this for $f''(x)$ and $f'''(x)$ will be very similar?